# Convert CSV from enum flags and vice versa

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

Consider the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    Option1 = 0,
    Option2 = 1,
    Option3 = 2,
    Option4 = 4
}
```

Is there a way in which I can get the string equivalent (not the value) as a CSV string? Normally I can use the [Enum.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx) function to convert a type to the string representation, however, if you use a combination this returns null.

So basically I would like to convert:

```
var options = MyEnum.Option1 | MyEnum.Option3;
```

into

```
"Option1, Option3"
```

Then I would like to be able to convert *"Option1, Option3"* back to `MyEnum.Option1 | MyEnum.Option2`.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does `enum.GetName` return null only when its a combination of values, or all the time?

Comment: @Kratz - Sorry just when it is a combination, I will update my post as it doesn't really make that clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, aside from `Option1` not making much sense in a flags enum, this just works by default using `Enum.Parse` and `Enum.ToString()`.

Start with this:

```
var options = MyEnum.Option2 | MyEnum.Option3;
Console.WriteLine(options.ToString());
// Outputs: Option2, Option3
```

Then you can always do this:

```
var options2 = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), "Option2, Option3");
```

Now try this:

```
Console.WriteLine((options2 & MyEnum.Option2) == MyEnum.Option2);
Console.WriteLine((options2 & MyEnum.Option4) == MyEnum.Option4);
// Outputs:
//    true
//    false
```

Which seems like it does exactly what you wanted (again, ignoring the fact that Option1 in your example will never occur)

docs: [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

Comment: I never actually realised `ToString()` would do that in .NET 3.5, I thought it was a .NET 4.0 feature... silly me. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `Enum.GetValues` which gets an array of enum values. You can then loop through those values and test them against your Enum value, concatenating the string value for each one that matches. The other way around you can loop through the values using the `Enum.GetName` function to test if your string contains that values name and then rebuild the value.